# system requirements for Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I installed blender in Ubuntu 16 , and I don't have any graphics cards in my CPU (JUST VIDEO CARD) , can I use blender for making 2d animation ? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Uhhhh... You can use Blender on basically any computer, it's just a question of how well it will work. (Buy the way, graphics cards and video cards are the same thing)

But yes, you *probably* will be able to run blender and make some animations.

Comment: There are Video Cards, Integrated Graphics (in the CPU or motherboard chipset) and GPUs (that may be in a Video Card). Blender will happily run with any combination or lack of these. Even run on machines with none of the above, just running on the CPU. 3D work is just Math :)